# Helpful tutorials for Modeling, sculpting, and shading

Tags: modeling, node-editor, shaders, sculpting

I have been using blender for about two years. And i am still lagging in molding, sculpting and shading knowledge would any one have some good wholesome and helpful tutorials?

Comment: this one is nice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZnUgt659oI

Comment: thanks i am in the process of downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro but any means but for me i find youtube really uselfull. i'm sure you are familiar, but the likes of Blender Guru & CGgeek. Longer video's help me learn from their workflow!

Comment: i have, and some was very helpful. Do you have any specific one that really helped and taught you

Comment: watch all of these parts, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pO58JyGh7SM

Comment: i am downloading one on sculpting would you have one on modeling PS i will keep yours in mind